# Set up Wordpress on the Amazon Cloud Computing

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2

I wish to set up wordpress on the Amazon Cloud Computing with Ubuntu 64 bit.
And I have got error as below:
**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 16777216 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 122880 bytes) in /var/www/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 759**

Please advise.

Best regards,

> **LeeJava**

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini change the parameter memory_limit and restart apache.